# Unable to publish app on the ios device whose MDM profile is "Not Verified"

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, enterprise, mdm

We have more than 900 iOS devices enrolled on MDM protal. In last month mdm profile for all devices changed to "Not verified". Due to this we are unable to publish apps on iOS devies. All commnds remains in pending states.
I did some research on it,  everyone is saying to reenroll the device which we really don't want to...
Any help would be really appreciated...

[Check attached screnshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU8hy.jpg)

Comment: Did maybe your signing certificate expire?

Comment: we have renewed it. When we enroll any new device it shows verified. But what about the previously enrolled devices. How we can change  their status from "not verified" to verified

Answer (score 0):

What Settings is showing there isn't a provisioning profile of the app but the trust of the certificate that signed the MDM enrollment profile.  The only way to change that would be to update or reinstall the MDM enrollment profile or determine what's failing in chaining the signing certificate to a trusted root certificate (you can guess which is usually easier).

That said, the MDM profile not being verified shouldn't have any impact on the MDM channel.  Are you sure you weren't affected by some bug like updating iOS via MDM with JAMF? https://9to5mac.com/2018/04/04/jamf-pro-mdm-ios-11-3/